Why does Flutter Desktop (Windows) and Web app pause which performinng a complex loop
i am working on a school timetable for my undergraduate project work. in My project i am using flutter and my app runs on both desktop and web. Anytime i am performing some looping and conditions, my application will pause (Freez) until the action is done. This cuase all other activities to stop such as circular progress and any other thing.
Note that i am using Riverpod for state management
Bellow is an example function that pause my app whhen it is called.
 void generateWithCombineClasses(WidgetRef ref)async {
    // CustomDialogs.loading(message: 'Generating table items for remaining Items');
    var config = ref.watch(configProvider).currentConfig;
    var vtps = ref
        .watch(venueTimePairProvider)
        .where((element) => element.isAssigned == false)
        .toList();
    var cclps = state.where((element) => element.isAssigned == false).toList();
    var tableItems = ref.watch(generatedTableProvider).items.toList();
    cclps.shuffle();

    List<VenueTimePairModel> usedVtps = [];
    for (var vtp in vtps) {
       
      if (!vtp.isAssigned && !usedVtps.contains(vtp)) {
        //pick all cclps that have not been assigned and a lecturer or class is not found in the existing table items
        var cclpsToAssign = cclps
            .where((element) =>
                !element.isAssigned &&
                !lecturerOrClassIsInTableItem(tableItems, element, vtp) &&
                isNotClassLiberalTime(vtp, element, config) &&
                isNotLecturerFreeDay(vtp, element) &&
                isEveningVenue(vtp, element, config) &&
                isEqual(element.venueType, vtp.venueType))
            .toList();
        if (cclpsToAssign.isNotEmpty) {
          //group cclps with same lecturer, same course, same class level and same study mode

          var groupByCriteria = groupBy(
              cclpsToAssign,
              (ClassCourseLecturerPairModel e) =>
                  '${e.courseId}-${e.level}-${e.studyMode}-${e.lecturerId}');
          //if no data meets the criteria we pick any cclp
          if (groupByCriteria.isEmpty) {
            //just pick any cclp that can fit the vtp capacity
            var cclp = cclpsToAssign.any(
                    (element) => element.classSize <= (vtp.venueCapacity + 35))
                ? cclpsToAssign.firstWhere(
                    (element) => element.classSize <= (vtp.venueCapacity + 35))
                : cclpsToAssign.firstOrNull;
            if (cclp != null) {
              var tableItem = makeTableItem(
                vtp: vtp,
                cclps: [cclp],
                config: config,
              );
              tableItems.add(tableItem);
              usedVtps.add(vtp);
              cclps = cclps
                  .map((element) => element.id == cclp.id
                      ? cclp.copyWith(isAssigned: true)
                      : element)
                  .toList();
            }
          } else {
            //pick any of the item that has the most number of cclps
            var valuesToList = groupByCriteria.values.toList();
            if (valuesToList.isNotEmpty) {
              var cclpWithHighestCount = groupByCriteria.values
                  .toList()
                  .reduce((value, element) =>
                      value.length > element.length ? value : element)
                  .toList();
              //here we check if 4 cclps can be combined to fit the vtp capacity
              //else check if 3 cclps can be combined to fit the vtp capacity
              //else check if 2 cclps can be combined to fit the vtp capacity
              //else check if 1 cclp can fit the vtp capacity
              //else we pick the cclp that can fit the vtp capacity
              if (cclpWithHighestCount.length > 3) {
                //we check if 4 cclps can be combined to fit the vtp capacity
                var totalCapacity = cclpWithHighestCount.sublist(0, 4).fold(
                    0,
                    (previousValue, element) =>
                        previousValue + element.classSize);
                if (totalCapacity <= (vtp.venueCapacity + 35)) {
                  var tableItem = makeTableItem(
                    vtp: vtp,
                    cclps: cclpWithHighestCount.sublist(0, 4),
                    config: config,
                  );
                  tableItems.add(tableItem);
                  usedVtps.add(vtp);
                  cclps = cclps
                      .map((element) =>
                          cclpWithHighestCount.sublist(0, 4).contains(element)
                              ? element.copyWith(isAssigned: true)
                              : element)
                      .toList();
                } else if (cclpWithHighestCount.sublist(0, 3).fold(
                        0,
                        (previousValue, element) =>
                            previousValue + element.classSize) <=
                    (vtp.venueCapacity + 35)) {
                  //we check if 3 cclps can be combined to fit the vtp capacity

                  var tableItem = makeTableItem(
                    vtp: vtp,
                    cclps: cclpWithHighestCount.sublist(0, 3),
                    config: config,
                  );
                  tableItems.add(tableItem);
                  usedVtps.add(vtp);
                  cclps = cclps
                      .map((element) =>
                          cclpWithHighestCount.sublist(0, 3).contains(element)
                              ? element.copyWith(isAssigned: true)
                              : element)
                      .toList();
                } else if (cclpWithHighestCount.sublist(0, 2).fold(
                        0,
                        (previousValue, element) =>
                            previousValue + element.classSize) <=
                    (vtp.venueCapacity + 35)) {
                  //we check if 2 cclps can be combined to fit the vtp capacity

                  var tableItem = makeTableItem(
                    vtp: vtp,
                    cclps: cclpWithHighestCount.sublist(0, 2),
                    config: config,
                  );
                  tableItems.add(tableItem);
                  usedVtps.add(vtp);
                  cclps = cclps
                      .map((element) =>
                          cclpWithHighestCount.sublist(0, 2).contains(element)
                              ? element.copyWith(isAssigned: true)
                              : element)
                      .toList();
                } else if (cclpWithHighestCount.first.classSize <=
                    (vtp.venueCapacity + 35)) {
                  //we check if 1 cclp can fit the vtp capacity

                  var tableItem = makeTableItem(
                    vtp: vtp,
                    cclps: cclpWithHighestCount.sublist(0, 1),
                    config: config,
                  );
                  tableItems.add(tableItem);
                  usedVtps.add(vtp);
                  cclps = cclps
                      .map((element) =>
                          cclpWithHighestCount.sublist(0, 1).contains(element)
                              ? element.copyWith(isAssigned: true)
                              : element)
                      .toList();
                } else {
                  //just just pick the smallest cclp and assign it to the vtp
                  var tableItem = makeTableItem(
                    vtp: vtp,
                    cclps: [cclpWithHighestCount.first],
                    config: config,
                  );
                  tableItems.add(tableItem);
                  usedVtps.add(vtp);
                  cclps = cclps
                      .map((element) =>
                          cclpWithHighestCount.sublist(0, 1).contains(element)
                              ? element.copyWith(isAssigned: true)
                              : element)
                      .toList();
                }
              } else if (cclpWithHighestCount.length > 2) {
                //we check if 3 cclps can be combined to fit the vtp capacity
                var totalCapacity = cclpWithHighestCount.sublist(0, 3).fold(
                    0,
                    (previousValue, element) =>
                        previousValue + element.classSize);
                if (totalCapacity <= (vtp.venueCapacity + 35)) {
                  var tableItem = makeTableItem(
                    vtp: vtp,
                    cclps: cclpWithHighestCount.sublist(0, 3),
                    config: config,
                  );
                  tableItems.add(tableItem);
                  usedVtps.add(vtp);
                  cclps = cclps
                      .map((element) =>
                          cclpWithHighestCount.sublist(0, 3).contains(element)
                              ? element.copyWith(isAssigned: true)
                              : element)
                      .toList();
                } else if (cclpWithHighestCount.sublist(0, 2).fold(
                        0,
                        (previousValue, element) =>
                            previousValue + element.classSize) <=
                    (vtp.venueCapacity + 35)) {
                  //we check if 2 cclps can be combined to fit the vtp capacity

                  var tableItem = makeTableItem(
                    vtp: vtp,
                    cclps: cclpWithHighestCount.sublist(0, 2),
                    config: config,
                  );
                  tableItems.add(tableItem);
                  usedVtps.add(vtp);
                  cclps = cclps
                      .map((element) =>
                          cclpWithHighestCount.sublist(0, 2).contains(element)
                              ? element.copyWith(isAssigned: true)
                              : element)
                      .toList();
                } else if (cclpWithHighestCount.first.classSize <=
                    (vtp.venueCapacity + 35)) {
                  //we check if 1 cclp can fit the vtp capacity

                  var tableItem = makeTableItem(
                    vtp: vtp,
                    cclps: cclpWithHighestCount.sublist(0, 1),
                    config: config,
                  );
                  tableItems.add(tableItem);
                  usedVtps.add(vtp);
                  cclps = cclps
                      .map((element) =>
                          cclpWithHighestCount.sublist(0, 1).contains(element)
                              ? element.copyWith(isAssigned: true)
                              : element)
                      .toList();
                } else {
                  //just just pick the smallest cclp and assign it to the vtp
                  var tableItem = makeTableItem(
                    vtp: vtp,
                    cclps: [cclpWithHighestCount.first],
                    config: config,
                  );
                  tableItems.add(tableItem);
                  usedVtps.add(vtp);
                  cclps = cclps
                      .map((element) =>
                          cclpWithHighestCount.sublist(0, 1).contains(element)
                              ? element.copyWith(isAssigned: true)
                              : element)
                      .toList();
                }
              } else if (cclpWithHighestCount.length > 1) {
                //we check if 2 cclps can be combined to fit the vtp capacity
                var totalCapacity = cclpWithHighestCount.sublist(0, 2).fold(
                    0,
                    (previousValue, element) =>
                        previousValue + element.classSize);
                if (totalCapacity <= (vtp.venueCapacity + 35)) {
                  var tableItem = makeTableItem(
                    vtp: vtp,
                    cclps: cclpWithHighestCount.sublist(0, 2),
                    config: config,
                  );
                  tableItems.add(tableItem);
                  usedVtps.add(vtp);
                  cclps = cclps
                      .map((element) =>
                          cclpWithHighestCount.sublist(0, 2).contains(element)
                              ? element.copyWith(isAssigned: true)
                              : element)
                      .toList();
                } else if (cclpWithHighestCount.first.classSize <=
                    (vtp.venueCapacity + 35)) {
                  //we check if 1 cclp can fit the vtp capacity

                  var tableItem = makeTableItem(
                    vtp: vtp,
                    cclps: cclpWithHighestCount.sublist(0, 1),
                    config: config,
                  );
                  tableItems.add(tableItem);
                  usedVtps.add(vtp);
                  cclps = cclps
                      .map((element) =>
                          cclpWithHighestCount.sublist(0, 1).contains(element)
                              ? element.copyWith(isAssigned: true)
                              : element)
                      .toList();
                } else {
                  //just just pick the smallest cclp and assign it to the vtp
                  var tableItem = makeTableItem(
                    vtp: vtp,
                    cclps: [cclpWithHighestCount.first],
                    config: config,
                  );
                  tableItems.add(tableItem);
                  usedVtps.add(vtp);
                  cclps = cclps
                      .map((element) =>
                          cclpWithHighestCount.sublist(0, 1).contains(element)
                              ? element.copyWith(isAssigned: true)
                              : element)
                      .toList();
                }
              } else {
                //we check if 1 cclp can fit the vtp capacity
                if (cclpWithHighestCount.first.classSize <=
                    (vtp.venueCapacity + 35)) {
                  var tableItem = makeTableItem(
                    vtp: vtp,
                    cclps: cclpWithHighestCount.sublist(0, 1),
                    config: config,
                  );
                  tableItems.add(tableItem);
                  usedVtps.add(vtp);
                  cclps = cclps
                      .map((element) =>
                          cclpWithHighestCount.sublist(0, 1).contains(element)
                              ? element.copyWith(isAssigned: true)
                              : element)
                      .toList();
                } else {
                  //just just pick the smallest cclp and assign it to the vtp
                  var tableItem = makeTableItem(
                    vtp: vtp,
                    cclps: [cclpWithHighestCount.first],
                    config: config,
                  );
                  tableItems.add(tableItem);
                  usedVtps.add(vtp);
                  cclps = cclps
                      .map((element) =>
                          cclpWithHighestCount.sublist(0, 1).contains(element)
                              ? element.copyWith(isAssigned: true)
                              : element)
                      .toList();
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      //await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    }
    ref.read(venueTimePairProvider.notifier).makeVTPAssigned(usedVtps);
    ref.read(generatedTableProvider.notifier).setTableItems(tableItems);
    //get unassigned cclps and vtps
    var unassignedCCLPs =
        cclps.where((element) => !element.isAssigned).toList();
    updateState(unassignedCCLPs);
    // for (var cclp in unassignedCCLPs) {
    //   print('........................................');
    //   print('${cclp.courseCode}: ${cclp.courseTitle}');
    //   print('CS: ${cclp.studyMode}: ClS: ${cclp.studyMode}');
    //   print(cclp.venueType);
    //   print('........................................');
    // }
    print('Number of unassigned cclps: ${unassignedCCLPs.length}');
    // var unassignedVTPs = ref
    var unassignedVTPs = ref
        .watch(venueTimePairProvider)
        .where((element) => !element.isAssigned)
        .toList();
    print('Number of unassigned vtps: ${unassignedVTPs.length}');
    //count all classes in table items
    var allClasses =
        tableItems.map((e) => e.classIds).expand((element) => element).toList();
    print('Number of table items: ${allClasses.length}');
    // ref.read(isLoadingProvider.notifier).state = (false, '');
    //CustomDialogs.dismiss();
  }


I tried to use Isolation(Compute) but was not able to figure out how to use it with this fuction.

please consider breaking up the generateWithCombineClasses into multiple distinct functions.  its WAYYYY too long

Regarding the "why" part of your question: it's because each Dart isolate is single-threaded, and all of this code runs in the main isolate that is responsible for rendering your UI and handling events.  If your loop is expensive, then the main isolate will be busy iterating in your loop instead iterating in its event loop, and your UI will be unresponsive.

@jamesdlin Is it possible to isolate this function? if so , how do i go about it
